# How to plot discret values using levelplot?

Tags: r

We have just 12 discret values in a raster, therefore I need just 12 colores. Is there a way not to show the scale as continus scale but a discret scale with levelplot? So each value corresponds to one colore and show exactly the number in the raster.for instance I have a value of 1.2 but I do not see it in the legend (scale).

```
library(rasterVis)
r <- raster(nrows=4, ncols=3); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
r[2,3]=9.5;r[1,3]=4.5;r[1,1]=1.2;levelplot(r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oscar Perpiñán, the maintainer of **rasterVis**, wrote a nice tutorial on how to [display categorial data](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#factor) using `levelplot`. Simply adjust your code as follows.

```
r <- ratify(r)

rasterVis::levelplot(r, att = "ID",
                     col.regions = rainbow(12))
```

[image: levelplot]